# Passing a reference to template function call operator overload

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-overloading, windows-8.1, function-call-operator

I have a class which overloads the function call operator with a template function, like so:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
        void operator()(T t)
    {
        std::cout<<(&t)<<std::endl;
    };
};
```

I'd like to call it with a reference argument, however when trying to do so, it passes the argument as a value instead. Here's my test setup:

```
template<class T>
    void test(T t) {std::cout<<(&t)<<std::endl;}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    Test t;
    int i = 5;
    std::cout<<(&i)<<std::endl;
    t((int&)i); // Passes the argument as a value/copy?
    test<int&>(i); // Passes the argument as a reference
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> 0110F738 -- Output of the address of 'i'
>
> 0110F664 -- Output of the address of the argument in the template overload
>
> 0110F738 -- Output of the address of the argument through 'test'

The template function 'test' is merely for validation.

The visual studio debugger confirms that it's using 'int' instead of 'int&' for the template overload:

> test_function_call.exe!Test::operator()(int t) Line 9  C++

How can I force it to use a reference instead? Is there a way to specify the types using <> on a template function call operator?

Comment: You want `void operator()(cont T& t)`

Comment: I don't want it to be 'const', I still need to be able to modify the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in your case the cv-qualifiers and the reference-ness of the parameter are discarded when performing template type deduction. Pass via a [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) wrapper instead

```
t(std::ref(i));
```

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void f(T param)
{
    ++param;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f(std::ref(i));
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // i is modified here, displays 1
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about std::ref, however the behavior doesn't change, it's still passing it as a value.

Comment: @Silverlan How do you know? It will "simulate" passing by reference if you e.g. modify `t` inside the `operator()`. Do something like `++t` inside, and you'll see the `i` will be modified.

Comment: That simulation is not the real thing- there are numerous ways to distinguish between `T&` and `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

Comment: You're right, it actually does work. But how come it still gives me a different address inside the operator() for 't'?

Comment: @Puppy indeed, I couldn't come up with a better wording ;)

Comment: @Silverlan because `std::ref` is an object of a different type that wraps internally a reference to what you passed, it just "looks" like a reference.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It's working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

You may use universal reference:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T&& t)
    {
        std::cout<<(&t)<<std::endl;
    };
};
```

Comment: Would I still be able to pass it as a value/copy using this way? I'd like to be able to do either.

Comment: @Silverlan not really, the type for `t` will be either deduced as `T&` or `T`, which after [reference collapsing](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) become `T&` and `T&&`.